# Set `display: none` recursively except for within a specific element

Tags: javascript, css

If I wanted to **hide** all elements except for those within a `<div id="content">` (**including** `div#content` itself), I could use the following CSS:

```css
*
{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

div#content, div#content *
{
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

One thing to note about this solution is that the hidden elements still take up space. Unfortunately, not all elements have the same `display` attribute, so you cannot simple simply replace `visibility` above with `display`.

Using JavaScript, how can I set all elements to that are **not** within the `<div id="#content">` 'family' to `display: none`?

Comment: I was under the impression that `visibility: collapse` only applies to `table` elements. *(Oh, the comment was deleted.)*

Comment: Is `#content` directly within the body?  That would simplify things considerably.

Comment: What about `#content`'s parent node??

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I'm not sure. I guess it depends on whether or not the parent needs to be displayed for `#content` to show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A general purpose solution to change the style on the fewest objects, but make sure that `#content` and all it's sub-elements are visible requires an  algorithm to traverse up from `#content` and hide all siblings at each level up without ever hiding an ancestor of `#content`.  Because this starts at `#content` and goes up, it never hides any elements inside of `#content`.

```
function hideAllExcept(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    while (el && el != document.body) {
        // go one level up
        var parent = el.parentNode;
        // get siblings of our ancesotr
        var siblings = parent.childNodes;
        // loop through the siblings of our ancestor, but skip out actual ancestor
        for (var i = 0, len = siblings.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (siblings[i] != el && siblings[i].nodeType == 1) {
                // only operate on element nodes
                siblings[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        el = parent;
    }
}

hideAllExcept("content");
```

Caveat: this first version does not hide text nodes that are siblings of an ancestor of #content (all other text nodes outside of #content are hidden because their parent is hidden).  To hide those text nodes too, they would have to get wrapped in a `<span>` tag so the style could be set on the `<span>` tag, but I don't know if the OP needs that level of complexity or wants the text nodes wrapped in that way.

For completeness, here's a version that will wrap parent sibling text nodes so they can also be set to `display: none`.  This may or may not be needed depending upon the source HTML:

```
function hideAllExcept(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    while (el && el != document.body) {
        // go one level up
        var parent = el.parentNode;
        // get siblings of our ancesotr
        var siblings = parent.childNodes;
        // loop through the siblings of our ancestor, but skip out actual ancestor
        for (var i = 0, len = siblings.length; i < len; i++) {
            var node = siblings[i];
            if (node != el) {
                if (node.nodeType == 1) {
                    // only operate on element nodes
                    node.style.display = "none";
                } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                    // wrap text node in span object so we can hide it
                    var span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.style.display = "none";
                    span.className = "xwrap";
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
                    // Be wary of the dynamic siblings nodeList changing 
                    // when we add nodes.  
                    // It actually works here because we add one 
                    // and remove one so the nodeList stays constant.
                    span.appendChild(node);
                }
            }
        }
        el = parent;
    }
}

hideAllExcept("content");​
```

And a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yVWDx/

Comment: Doesn't `childNodes` include text nodes, which don't have a `style` property?

Comment: @JamesMontagne - good catch James.  I've modified it to only set style on element nodes.  I don't think one can hide a plain text node without either removing it or wrapping it in a `<span>` and hiding the span.  I don't know whether that extra level of complexity is needed by the OP or not.  I added caveat to my answer explaining.

Comment: @jfriend00 This works. :) Great, clear answer, by the way. I just started learning JavaScript and your comments were helpful.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - I added a second version that wraps naked ancesotr sibling text nodes so they can be hidden too.

Comment: Very nice.  I was actually only pointing it out because it would blow up on text nodes.  Nice addition of the wrapping though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var al = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(var i =0;i<al.length;i++)
{
    var elm = al[i];
    if(elm.parentNode.id != 'content') {
        elm.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that hide all of `#content`'s grandchildren?

Comment: I guess any solution given would hide #content's grandchildren. As the children gets the CSS property display:none, the grandchildren wont be visible anyways.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify. `#content` should not be set to `display: none`.